# Apache with port 80 and 443

Tags: apache, xampp, port

```
11:05:46 AM  [Apache]   Problem detected!
11:05:46 AM  [Apache]   Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 6476!
11:05:46 AM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:05:46 AM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:05:46 AM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
11:05:46 AM  [Apache]   Problem detected!
11:05:46 AM  [Apache]   Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 6476!
11:05:46 AM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:05:46 AM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:05:46 AM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

This is the error i get from my xamppp control panel but this is the print screen of my skype

[image]

It shows I already uncheck the port for 80 and 433

How to fix this.

Comment: is there another web server running on your host?

Comment: i am only using xampp. i doubt there is

Comment: maybe lookup process is 6476 in your process list